# iPad Air WiFi + Cellular, but no cellular settings?

Tags: ipad, wifi, settings, cellular-data

I have an iPad Air 16gb I bought off a popular classifieds website. It was advertised as WiFi only, and in the settings there is only WiFi. But when I look up the serial number on Apple's site, it says it's WiFi + Cellular. I've corroborated this on several other Apple serial lookup sites. Am I missing something? Is there something I have to activate to get the cellular settings to appear?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but thanx.

Comment: Keep in mind - an old question without an answer isn't reason not to vote to close. It's best to edit this post so it's 100% clear to all how you have a fundamentally different question. We should put a bounty on the old question if this is a rehash of it.